# Get a sum using as many numbers in a set as possible

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given three numbers, all of them positive. Two numbers that you may add together and a maximum. I must return the *largest* amount of numbers I can add together while remaining under or being just at the maximum limit. In other words:

I am provided two numbers **n** and **m**, and the sum **s**. Find largest possible amount that **a+b** can be, if:

`a * n + b * m <= s`

I do think that I have a working (yet over-complicated and long) solution if the two numbers add exactly up to the sum, but if there's a remainder then it breaks.

For example, if the two numbers are 3 and 5 and the sum is 54, then the answer is 18.

Comment: Can you also provide sample input and output?

Comment: Wouldn't you just take the smaller of the two numbers as many times as possible, and the other number zero times?

Comment: Can **n** and **m** be negative integers?

Comment: @Kyrylo if n or m are negative, then the answer is infinity.

Comment: @n.m. Yes, so I asked this question because of this reason.

Comment: @n.m. I find it ironic the question calls for `n` and `m` and you answered with the name "n.m."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer will always be the max number of time the smaller of `m, n` will div into `s`.

#### Code:

```
max_a_plus_b = divmod(s, min(n, m))
```

#### Why:

The answer (a+b) is the raw count of instances of `m` and `n`.  If you start with the assumption that `max_a_plus_b` is the number of times the smaller of `m, n` will div  in `s`.  Then taking one less of that factor and one more of the other factor will give the same `a+b` but a larger `s`, so the answer is already optimal at that point.